# Mounting SMB3 share with encryption fails: mount error(13): Permission denied (Synology)

Tags: encryption, cifs, smb

Everything works fine until I add encryption on my synology, from that point on I only get

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
```

I've tried this command:

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.178.22/Filme /home/john/Filme/ -o credentials=/home/john/.smbcredentials,vers=3.0,domain=WORKGROUP
```

I've also tried every sec= option, without success.

In case it matters, I'm running arch linux, kernel 3.19.8-1.

Answer (score 4):

SMB3-encrypted shares are supported [since kernel version 4.8.0-54.57](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1670508).

As **cifs** driver is a part of Linux kernel, it is updated accordingly and you need to upgrade to the latest kernel to overcome this error.  To force encryption, you have to add the not-yet-documented mount option *seal* in combination with *vers=3.0*.

Answer (score 2):

All I found on the internet seems to indicate encryption is currently not implemented yet by the Linux cifs filesystem driver. Also, in the mount.cifs(8) manpage of my Centos 7, for the 'sec=' option, there's no mode stating packet encryption, only packet signing (the modes with 'i' appended to their regular names). For comparison, the nfs(5) manpage lists modes with 'i' appended, for packet signing, and also modes with 'p' appended, for full packet encryption.

So I believe this is not yet available for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

SMB 3.0 encryption support was introduced in Linux kernel version 4.11 and has been backported to older kernel versions for popular Linux distributions.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this in case of others still trying to find a solution. I was getting similar issues and found that the smb credentials file had to have a separate line for domain - mine had username as DOMAIN\username which worked fine for SMB v1 but not with later versions of the protocol.

With regards to your particular issue, I read elsewhere someone else having trouble with a Synology device and they had to explicitly enable SMB v3 on the Synology which resolved it for them.